# Maximum degree for this set of planar graphs where all neighbours of any point lie on a circle centered on that point

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, analytic-geometry, conjectures, planar-graphs

Consider an undirected simple planar graph, with these additional restrictions:

- The plane in which the graph is embedded has a Cartesian coordinate system, and there's an injective function mapping each node to its pair of coordinates. I.e., no two nodes lie on the same point of the plane.
- Each node maps to **integer** coordinates. I.e., the nodes lie on a **grid**.
- For any node, call it $A$, all neighbors of $A$ lie on a **circle** centered on $A$. I.e., all neighbors of any node have the **same distance** to that node.

I couldn't draw a graph like this with max degree greater than $4$, so I'm wondering whether $4$ is indeed the max degree for this set of graphs. If not $4$, perhaps it's $5$ or $6$?

Edit: now I mechanically found the maximal degree of a graph from this set to be 16, so the conjecture is disproved. It would still be nice if someone gave an answer that explains this intuitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) you can find integers that are written as the sum of two squares in arbitrarily many ways. For example from $5^2=3^2+4^2$ and $13^2=5^2+12^2$ we get $65^2=63^2+16^2=56^2+33^2$.

From this you can make a star graph, centre at $(0,0)$, connected to $20$ equidistant vertices at
$(\pm65,0)$,
$(0,\pm65)$,
$(\pm63,\pm16)$,
$(\pm16,\pm63)$,
$(\pm56,\pm33)$,
$(\pm33,\pm56)$.

By multiplying this by for example $17^2=8^2+15^2$ you find that there are $36$ grid points at a distance of $65\cdot17=1105$ from the origin.